# Display bootstrap wells on left and right side of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap wells to resemble cards. I currently have two different types of cards, the "normal" ones which will be in the middle of the screen, and the "special" ones which will be on the left and right side.

**Template I'm trying to replicate:**

[image: template]

**Issues:**

1.) It seems like the wells in bootstrap don't want to go to the very left or right of a page. They seem to always be contained in an invisible div/border and won't go anywhere else unless absolute positioning is used. I can't use absolute positioning because the middle content overlaps it if zoomed in. It gets rid of the responsive aspect of bootstrap which needs to stay.

2.) Without the use of absolute positioning, making new "special" cards on the side will add extra vertical space which will sink the middle content down the page

```css
body {
  background-color: #5C67B6;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.btn-purple {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5C67B6;
  border-color: #5C67B6;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -140px;
}

.btn-info {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5C67B6;
  border-color: #5C67B6;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 10%;
  margin-left: 140px;
}

.btn-info:hover,
.btn-info:focus,
.btn-info:active,
.btn-info.active,
.open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-info {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4b5496;
  border-color: #4b5496;
}

.btn-purple:hover,
.btn-purple:focus,
.btn-purple:active,
.btn-purple.active,
.open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-purple {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4b5496;
  border-color: #4b5496;
}

.customClass {
  width: 700px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.turbo {
  background: #7280e5;
  color: white;
  border-color: #4b5496;
}

.well {
  min-height: 320px;
  max-height: 320px;
  height: auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}

.well:hover {
  background: #7280e5;
  color: white;
  border-color: #4b5496;
}

.well p {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.header {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.playerOne {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid #dadada;
  background-color: #dadada;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #5dbcd2;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #5dbcd2;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #5dbcd2;
}

.playerTwo {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid #dadada;
  background-color: #dadada;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #5dbcd2;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #5dbcd2;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #5dbcd2;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .playerOne {
    width: 650px;
  }
  .playerTwo {
    width: 633px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="header">
  <div class="playerOne">
    Special Cards
  </div>
  <div class="playerTwo">
    Special Cards
  </div>
</div>

<center>
  <div class="input-group" style="width: 500px; padding-bottom: 2cm;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search cards!">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
  </div>
  <!-- /input-group -->
</center>
<div class="content">
  <div class="container content-sm customClass">
    <div class="row">
      <center>
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
          <ul class="pagination">
            <li>
              <a aria-label="Previous" href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
              <a href="#">1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">5</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a aria-label="Next" href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </center>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well">
          <img class="center-block" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" style="border-radius: 50%;" height="80" width="80">
          <h3 style="text-align: center;">Card</h3>
          <p>This is Text. This is Text. This is Text. </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Button!</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Button!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well">
          <img class="center-block" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" style="border-radius: 50%;" height="80" width="80">
          <h3 style="text-align: center;">Card</h3>
          <p>This is Text. This is Text. This is Text. This is Text. This is Text. This is Text. This is Text. </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Button!</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Button!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well turbo">
          <img class="center-block" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" style="border-radius: 50%;" height="80" width="80">
          <h3 style="text-align: center;">Card</h3>
          <p>This is Text. This is Text. This is Text. </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Button!</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Button!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well">
          <img class="center-block" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" style="border-radius: 50%;" height="80" width="80">
          <h3 style="text-align: center;">Card</h3>
          <p>This is Text. This is Text. This is Text. </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm" style="vertical-align: bottom;"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Button!</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Button!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well">
          <img class="center-block" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" style="border-radius: 50%;" height="80" width="80">
          <h3 style="text-align: center;">Card</h3>
          <p>This is Text. This is Text. This is Text. This is Text. </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Button!</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well">
          <img class="center-block" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" style="border-radius: 50%;" height="80" width="80">
          <h3 style="text-align: center;">Card</h3>
          <p>This is Text. This is Text. This is Text. This is Text. </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Button!</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Button!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using a flexbox and putting the wells in there which seemed to work until i zoomed in and noticed it was no longer responsive and overlapped the other content.

What is the best and most efficient way of adding wells to the left and right side of the page without adding unnecessary whitespace and maintaining responsiveness?

Comment: Do you specifically need to maintain a vertical 'flow' for your content? Like the three boxes on the outsides are 'associated' with each other? If not, you could consider the boxes from a horizontal viewpoint, and simply use four columns. In fact, you could do that even if the cards needs to be grouped, and then you could change the DIV 'position' that the cards are 'inserted' into.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I'm not sure why javascript was the first tag selected on this. I typed css first because i really only wanted a css solution but i'll use JS if required. Yes they need to be vertical. Have a look at https://discordlist.me/ this is the style i'm trying to replicate.

Comment: I tried to do this https://embed.plnkr.co/v5tGdurseZWmjTm8mJM7/.

Comment: @WilliamValhakis is it possible to do this in pure css and resize the boxes in the middle to match the ones in my example? All boxes should have the same width but this is exactly what I want. I just prefer to not use javascript if it's possible in pure css.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below example to get the same use `col-xx-offset-xx` bootstrap's classes

I posted a working example

You can use `container-fluid` instead of `container`.

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
      <div class="box">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="box">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="box">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
      <div class="box">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="box">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="box">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working codepen - **[codepen](https://codepen.io/Lokeshg27/pen/gRGomX?editors=1100)**

Comment: Could you edit the answer and apply this to the wells in the question? The special cards need to be on the very end of each side of the page (left and right) but these boxes are still positioned in the middle-ish part of the page. I tried working with wells using your answer but it just broke them and it was all spaced out. Have a look at: https://embed.plnkr.co/v5tGdurseZWmjTm8mJM7/ for reference of what I want except they all need to be the same width and height. The special cards should have a bit of space and not be so close to the normal ones in the middle.

Comment: I used a box div so,  there is no much effort simply put your `wells` into the box div and some css stuff as requirement if need.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea how to do it with fixed sizes, css is hard.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="well">header row</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="well">x-well</div>
      <div class="well">x-well</div>
      <div class="well">x-well</div>
      <div class="well">x-well</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="well">
        sample text
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="well">x-well</div>
          <div class="well">x-well</div>
          <div class="well">x-well</div>
          <div class="well">x-well</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="well">x-well</div>
          <div class="well">x-well</div>
          <div class="well">x-well</div>
          <div class="well">x-well</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="well">x-well</div>
      <div class="well">x-well</div>
      <div class="well">x-well</div>
      <div class="well">x-well</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```